# In Coq: inversion of existential quantifier with multiple variables, with one command?

Tags: exists, coq, inversion

I am working through a proof in which there is a hypothesis

```
H : exists a b v, P a b v
```

If I use `inversion H`, then I recover

```
a : nat
H1 : exists b v, P a b v.
```

which is fine, but then I need to use inversion twice more to recover b and v. 
Is there a single command to recover a, b, v all at once?

Comment: Thanks for both of these quick answers. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list of patterns `(p1 & ... & pn)` for sequence of right-associative binary inductive constructors such as `conj` or `ex_intro`:

```
destruct H as (a & b & v & H).
```

Another nice example from the reference manual: if we have a hypothesis

```
H: A /\ (exists x, B /\ C /\ D)
```

Then, we can destruct it with

```
destruct H as (a & x & b & c & d).
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by specifying binders for the objects you want to introduce, like this:

```
inversion [a [b [v H']]].
```

Note that `destruct` also works here (with the same syntax), it generates a slightly simpler proof (In general, the manual warns against large proofs generated by `inversion`).